# How to ask for windows authentication with python

Tags: python, security

When I forget a password and need to check it in chrome, It asks me enter my PIN for my laptop before viewing, in a windows authorisation dialog. Does anybody know how to access this with python? 
Ask for the PC's login password with python?

Here is the dialog i'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: You probably need to convert this into Python using cpython, pywin32. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134882/show-authentication-dialog-in-c-sharp-for-windows-vista-7. Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincred/nf-wincred-creduipromptforwindowscredentialsa

Comment: Search github for `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsA`, you'll find many code examples. https://github.com/search?q=CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsA&type=Code. But none in Python :/

Comment: Do you know if this function is available in the `pywin32` module?

Comment: It doesn't seem so :(

Comment: This question got me interested. I'll post updates as I figure this stuff out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067175/trying-to-call-wincred-api-using-ctypes

Comment: Something similar: https://gist.github.com/exhuma/a310f927d878b3e5646dc67dfa509b42

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this as well. - `pywin32` does have one, but its... not the dialogue I'm looking for. Will add a screenshot in the question.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/125314/how-do-i-call-a-dialog-for-authentication might help? If there is a windows equivalent?

Comment: It may not be ideal, but you could try compiling a barebones app that takes prompts for credentials in C# and call it in Python

Comment: Hmm. Will give that a go... In c++ probably though...